# How to send data from PC to arduino?

Tags: arduino-ide

How can I read data in Arduino IDE from a text file, if I have a text file which has the angle of arm at the different time intervals? If I want to read a text file from PC, can anyone please show the demonstration code as well? I am attaching a code where I am writing a position to servo1 whose values I want to give via text file.

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo myservo1 ;   
int pos1 = 0;     


void setup() {
  myservo1.attach(4);   //inner
}

void loop() {
   myservo1.write(pos1); // pos1 I will give different angles via text file
}
```

If I am not using SD card module, how can I do this with PC only? Someone please help.

Comment: Can you show us the code you have written so far? Are you using an SD card reader module? Perhaps processing could be used to communicate between the PC and Arduino? Please update your question with more information.

Comment: I edited accordingly with the code, now someone reply, please.

Comment: Use python to read the text file and send it to the arduino via serial. Use the `serial` library for python and `Serial` on the arduino side.

Comment: your code has nothing to do with the problem ... you need to realize that the data transfer between a PC and the Arduino is totally separate from the servo control ... what you do with the received data is irrelevant ... at this point you need to solve the data transfer problem

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to store multiple values in the text file, and then
have the Arduino IDE (not the Arduino itself) read the file and insert
the data into your sketch. If this is really what your question is
about, a quick and dirty solution would be as follows:

1. Format the text file as a list of comma-separated numbers, either in
   one or several lines. For example:

```
1, 12, 23, 34, 45, 56, 67,
78, 89, 100
```

2. Include this file in your sketch as the body of an array initializer:

```cpp
#include <Servo.h>

const int positions[] = {
#include "full_path_of_the_file_holding_the_positions"
};
#define positions_length (sizeof positions / sizeof positions[0])

Servo myservo1;   

void setup() {
    myservo1.attach(4);
}

void loop() {
    for (int i = 0; i < positions_length; i++) {
        myservo1.write(positions[i]);
        delay(200);
    }
}
```

Comment: This helped me somewhat, thanks. Now I have a lot of variables and data that I will be sending to arduino IDE, Is there any size limit that Arduino accepts. I have a very big set of data for SERVO control.

Comment: @ShivamGoswami: Each board has a fixed amount of available flash and RAM memory. If you have lots of constant data, `PROGMEM` should help: do a Web search for that term.